# Windows 10 IoT Core / .NET Core 2.0 / Where to store data?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, windows-iot-core-10

I was asking me what might be a good approach to persist app-relevant data in my .NET Core 2.0 application. The app runs on a Pi3 with Windows 10 IoT Core. As I can see I only have two choices. 1. MSSQL LocalDB or 2. SQLite. Azure or other cloud services won't work as my app is offline. I know that this is not the intended use case of Win10IoT and stuff, but maybe someone has ideas?

Comment: SQLite is lightweight and fit for IoT solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using SQLite now. First impression is positive - but you have to keep the [SQLite EF Core Database Provider Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations) in mind. Applying more than one EF Migration was not possible in my case as I wanted to `AlterColumn`. I had to revert any Migration and than repeat Add-Migration to migrate the complete model at once.